# jq to prefix a string in a json object with a string

Tags: json, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, jq

I am looking to generate a manifest file for a Redshift `COPY` with a combination of `aws s3api --list-objects` and `jq` as below:-

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket annalects3 --prefix "DFA/20160926/394007-OMD-Coles/dcm_account394007_impression" --output json --query '{"entries": Contents[].{"url":"Key"}}' | jq '.entries[].mandatory = true'
```

which generates an output like below:-

```
    {   "entries": [
        {
          "mandatory": true,
          "url": "DFA/20160926/394007-OMD-Coles/dcm_account394007_impression_2016092507_20160926_002328_292527438.csv.gz"
        },
        {
          "mandatory": true,
          "url": "DFA/20160926/394007-OMD-Coles/dcm_account394007_impression_2016092508_20160926_020131_292592736.csv.gz"
        },
        {
          "mandatory": true,
          "url": "DFA/20160926/394007-OMD-Coles/dcm_account394007_impression_2016092509_20160926_030312_292502379.csv.gz"
        },
        {
          "mandatory": true,
          "url": "DFA/20160926/394007-OMD-Coles/dcm_account394007_impression_2016092510_20160926_033656_292590227.csv.gz"
        }   
  ] 
}
```

The manifest file, however needs the URL objects prefixed with a bucket-name which I haven't got around with. The output needs to look as

```
{   "entries": [
        {
          "mandatory": true,
          "url": "s3://mybucket/DFA/20160926/394007-OMD-Coles/dcm_account394007_impression_2016092507_20160926_002328_292527438.csv.gz"
        },
        {
          "mandatory": true,
          "url": "s3://mybucket/DFA/20160926/394007-OMD-Coles/dcm_account394007_impression_2016092508_20160926_020131_292592736.csv.gz"
        },
        {
          "mandatory": true,
          "url": "s3://mybucket/DFA/20160926/394007-OMD-Coles/dcm_account394007_impression_2016092509_20160926_030312_292502379.csv.gz"
        },
        {
          "mandatory": true,
          "url": "s3://mybucket/DFA/20160926/394007-OMD-Coles/dcm_account394007_impression_2016092510_20160926_033656_292590227.csv.gz"
        }   
  ] 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the following will achieve what you want

```
aws s3api list-objects \
    --bucket <mybucket> \
    --prefix "<myprefix>" \
    --output json \
    --query '{"entries": Contents[].{"url":"Key"}}' \
| jq '.entries[] | .url = "s3://<mybucket>/\(.entries.url)" | .mandatory = true'
```

I am using [String interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C%28foo%29) to update the `entries[].url` values

Comment: just realized that the objects were repeating 24 times. I mean `{
  "entries": [
    {
      "mandatory": true,
      "url": "s3://annalects3/DFA/20160926/394007-OMD-Coles/dcm_account394007_impression_2016092607_20160926_235248_292871264.csv.gz"
    },
] }
` seems to have duplicated 24 times.

Comment: Are you sure you dont have 24 items in your bucket ? It works for me correctly

Comment: can you run `aws s3api list-objects --bucket <mybucket>` and compare with the results you get. jq will not create more entries than you get so I really don't see where the duplicate can come from, they must come from aws cli

Comment: The `aws s3api list-objects --bucket <mybucket>` isn't generating any duplicates and is listing all the objects of the array. Stackoverflow does't seem to allow insertion of any images or maybe I am unaware of how to do it.

Comment: oops got it, I fixed it, I had an issue indeed with the array, now it will work and will show only distinct elements and no duplicate

Answer (score 1):

This below works perfectly fine for me. The above suggestion did not give comma separated dictionary

```
aws s3api list-objects \
--bucket "xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxx" \
--output json \
--query "{"entries": Contents[?LastModified>='YYYY-MM-DD' && contains(Key,'somestring') ].{"url":"Key"}}" \
| jq '[.entries[] | .url = "s3://xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxx/\(.url)" | .mandatory = true] | { entries: .}' > test_jq1.json

I am not able to add content_length to the above solution as below with "meta" as dictionary.  Any help is greatly appreciated 

{
  "entries": [
    {
      "url":"s3://my-bucket/file1.parquet",
      "mandatory":true,
      "meta":{
        "content_length":2893394
      }
    },
    {
      "url":"s3://my-bucket/file2.parquet",
      "mandatory":true,
      "meta":{
        "content_length":2883626
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: KAN PANCHAL, you are asking for help, aren't you?